# How to redirect client program on a new arbitrary port in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a client-server program in C. I want the client to connect to the server on a specific port 5555. After the server accepts the connection, I want the server to send back the arbitrary port to the client. In order to redirect the client to that port where the client can send information. My problem is that the client receives the new port but is unable to connect to the server via that port

The client source code is the following (graham.c):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PORT 5555 
#define MAX_USERNAME_SIZE 16
#define MAX_FILENAME_SIZE 255
#define BUFFSIZE 1024

char *extract_filename_from_path(char *pathname);
char *extract_filename_from_path(char *pathname)
{
    char *last = strrchr(pathname, '/');
    return (last != NULL) ? last + 1 : pathname;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd1, sockfd2, numbytes;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
    struct hostent *he;
    FILE *photo;
    char buff[BUFFSIZE];
    short status = 1;

    // verifier le nombre d'arguments
    if (argc != 7)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Compléter sa commande de la façon suivante:\n"
                "graham ip_serveur nom_utilisateur_dans_le_pool"
                   " /chemin/vers/la/photo année mois jour");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((he = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Client: gethostbyname");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // initialiser le socket 1
    if ((sockfd1 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: socket");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    their_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)he->h_addr);
    memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

    if (connect(sockfd1, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, 
                sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: connect 1");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // get port
    short int port;
    if (recv(sockfd1, &port, sizeof(short int), 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: recv port");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }   
    printf("recieved port: %d\n", ntohs(port));
    close(sockfd1);
    // changer de port
    // initialiser le socket 2
    if ((sockfd2 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: socket");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    their_addr.sin_port = port; 
    their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)he->h_addr);
    memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

    if (connect(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, 
                sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: connect 2");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // 2) envoyer le nom d'utilisateur
    if (send(sockfd2, argv[2], MAX_USERNAME_SIZE, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: send username");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // 3) envoyer la date de prise
    if (send(sockfd2, argv[4], 5, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: send year");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (send(sockfd2, argv[5], 3, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: send month");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (send(sockfd2, argv[6], 3, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: send day");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // 4) envoyer le nom de l'image
    if (send(sockfd2, extract_filename_from_path(argv[3]), MAX_FILENAME_SIZE, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: send filename");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    // 5) envoyer l'image au client
    if ((photo = fopen(argv[3], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Client: fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    do
    {
        if ((numbytes = write(sockfd2, buff, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbytes; i++)
            {
                buff[i] = getc(photo);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    fclose(photo);
    // 6) recevoir et traiter le code de retour
    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd2, &status, sizeof(short int), 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client: recv return code");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ((status = ntohs(status)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Echec de la transaction");
    }
    close(sockfd2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the server source code is (spbx.c):

```
#include "spbx.h"

int my_read(FILE *target, const int source_fd)
{
    char buff[BUFFSIZE];
    memset(buff, '\0', BUFFSIZE);
    int numbytes;
    int status = 0;
    if ((numbytes = read(source_fd, buff, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbytes; i++)
        {
            putc(buff[i], target);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        status = -1;    
    }
    return status;
}
int my_mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode)
{
    struct stat s;
    int status = 0;
    if (stat(path, &s) == -1)
    {
        if (mkdir(path, mode) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
        {
            status = -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        errno = ENOTDIR;
        status = -1;
    }
    return status;
}
int init_socket(int *sockfd, const short int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    int yes = 1;
    if ((*sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: socket");
        return -1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(*sockfd, SOL_SOCKET,
                SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: setsockopt");
        return -1;
    }
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);
    if (bind(*sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr,
                sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: bind");
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(*sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: listen");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int recv_date(int new_fd, char **year, char **month, char **day)
{
    int numbytes;
    if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, year, 5, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: recv year");
        return -1;
    }
    if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, month, 3, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: recv month");
        return -1;
    }
    if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, day, 3, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: recv day");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ecouter sur sockfd et etablir la nouvelle
    // connexion sur new_fd
    int sockfd1, sockfd2, new_fd, numbytes, photo_tmp_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
    unsigned int sin_size;
    char username[MAX_USERNAME_SIZE];
    char filename[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];
    char path_tmp[MAX_FILEPATH_SIZE];
    char path[MAX_FILEPATH_SIZE];
    memset(path, '\0', MAX_FILEPATH_SIZE);
    char year[5], month[3], day[3];
    FILE *photo_tmp;
    FILE *photo;
    short int status = 1;
    fd_set readfds;
    int max;

    // verifier le nombre d'arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Donner le chemin vers le pool 2\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // initialiser les socket

    if(init_socket(&sockfd1, MY_PORT) == -1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(init_socket(&sockfd2, 0) == -1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

    if (getsockname(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, &sin_size) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: getsockname");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while (1)
    {
        //initialisation du fd_set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(sockfd1, &readfds);
        FD_SET(sockfd2, &readfds);
        max = (sockfd1 < sockfd2)? sockfd2 : sockfd1;
        select(max + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd1, &readfds))
        {
            // on envoie le port
            if ((new_fd = accept(sockfd1,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,
                    &sin_size)) == -1)
            {
                perror("Serveur: accept 1");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            printf("Serveur: connexion reçue du client %s\n",
                    inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                close(sockfd1);
                if (send(new_fd, &my_addr.sin_port, sizeof(short int), 0) == -1)
                {
                    perror("Serveur: send port");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            close(new_fd);
        }
        else if (FD_ISSET(sockfd2, &readfds))
        {
            if ((new_fd = accept(sockfd2,
                (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) == -1)
            {
                perror("Serveur: accept 2");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            printf("Serveur: connexion reçue du client %s redirigé vers le port %d\n",
                inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(my_addr.sin_port));

            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                close(sockfd1);
                close(sockfd2);

                // 2) recevoir l'utilisateur du pool sous forme
                // de chaîne de caractères
                if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, &username, MAX_USERNAME_SIZE, 0)) == -1)
                {
                    perror("Serveur: recv username");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                // 3) récevoir la date de prise de vue
                if(recv_date(new_fd, (char **) &year, (char **)&month, (char **)  &day) == -1) 
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;

                // 4) recevoir le nom du fichier
                if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, &filename, MAX_FILENAME_SIZE, 0)) == -1)
                {
                    perror("Serveur: recv filename");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                // 5) recevoir l'image téléversée par le client
                sprintf(path_tmp, "/tmp/%s", filename);
                if ((photo_tmp = fopen(path_tmp, "w")) == NULL)
                {
                    perror("Serveur: fopen");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                do
                {
                    if (my_read(photo_tmp, sockfd2) == -1) break;
                }while(1);
                fclose(photo_tmp);

                // 6) creer l'arborescence

                sprintf(path, "%s/%s", argv[1], username);
                my_mkdir(path, MODE);

                sprintf(path, "%s/%s/%s", argv[1], username, year);
                my_mkdir(path, MODE);

                sprintf(path, "%s/%s/%s/%s", argv[1], username, year, month);
                my_mkdir(path, MODE);

                sprintf(path, "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s", argv[1], username, year, month, day);
                my_mkdir(path, MODE);

                sprintf(path, "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s", argv[1], username, year, month, day, filename);


                // 7) Enregistrement de la photographie
                if ((photo = fopen(path, "w")) == NULL 
                        || (photo_tmp_fd = open(path_tmp, O_WRONLY)) == -1)
                {
                    perror("Serveur: fopen");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                do
                {
                    if (my_read(photo, photo_tmp_fd) == -1) break;
                }while(1);
                close(photo_tmp_fd);
                fclose(photo);

                // 8) enoyer le code 0 en cas de success
                status = htons(0);
                if (send(new_fd, &status, sizeof(short int), 0) == -1)
                {
                    perror("Serveur: send code");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }   
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;

            }
            close(new_fd);//9) deconnexion
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "erreur de select\n");
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the following result when I run the server and try two times to connect to it with the client program:

server side:

```
Serveur: connexion reçue du client 127.0.0.1
Serveur: connexion reçue du client 127.0.0.1
```

client side:

```
recieved port: 4645
Client: connect 2: Connection refused
recieved port: 4645
Client: connect 2: Connection refused
```

The only thing I noticed is that the port stays the same for the same execution of the server and multiple execution of the client. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you create the new socket *after* the client connects, not before?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I create the new socket  just after the client connects and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: So if you've fixed your code, you might as well close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have created the new socket after the clients connects as mentioned by
@ChrisTurner. So I moved the following lines:

```
if(init_socket(&sockfd2, 0) == -1) return EXIT_FAILURE;

if (getsockname(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, &sin_size) == -1)
{
    perror("Serveur: getsockname");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

right after the first `accept()` and before the `fork()` in server program.